# Visual Studio 2012 "Find in Files" searches far beyond the solution when "Entire Solution" is specified

Tags: visual-studio-2012

While performing Find and Replace operations in Visual Studio 2012; using the Find in Files/Replace in Files dialog window, setting the "Look in" scope to "Entire Solution", and using Regular Expressions on all file types, Visual Studio is busy searching the WHOLE HARD DRIVE!  Some of my searches take a very long time and when I look at the Visual Studio Status Bar, it shows the currently searched directory/file is something well outside of the solution folders - sometimes it is even searching the C:\Windows\System32 directory or similarly irrelevant locations.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?  More importantly, does anyone have a solution to fix it, so my search and replace operations stick to the solution files and don't waste time searching the other million files on the computer?

Comment: Never heard of such a thing, make sure you have updated Visual Studio 2012 with all the latest fixes and patches, Update 3 is the latest: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/visual-studio-update

Comment: I think Visual Studio is current: `Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012, Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3`, `Microsoft .Net Framework, Version 4.5.50709`, many of the installed options have `04941-004-0043007-02689` as their version ID.  However, my company attempts to limit non-system-admins from doing their own updates; unfortunately, that means developers, such as myself, cannot always update our development platforms.

Comment: Can confirm that it's still happening in VS 2015 Update 2. (Note that this is not the latest version of VS 2015.)

Comment: Over the course of time, my machine has been updated and Visual Studio as well. The problem stopped occurring at some point, but I don't recall the specifics of when or how - I'm just guessing that a system or VS update/replacement "fixed" the issue. Or maybe my fixing of another issue (by deleting *.suo files or the like) may have fixed this problem...

Answer (score 12):

I've not had it searching the whole drive, but I have had it return matches from files outside my project (this in VS 2010).  In my case deleting the .suo file appeared to fix this issue.

My suspicion is that the files being searched are files I stepped into during a debugging session (or more accurately stepped out of my code into the calling code).  Somehow these files are remembered and included in searches.

This wouldn't explain a full drive search, but could explain my "out of solution" results

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not this is the case.  It seems that some files which are located in within sub-folders of the project, or perhaps sub-folders of sibling folders to the project, or often included in whole solution searches.

I may have to try deleting the *.suo file...

Comment: I also experienced this after copying a project to another location. Deleting hte .csproj.user file + restart VS 2017 fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar problem with Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4 installed - in my case I was getting search results from files that had been in the Miscellaneous Files 'Project', even after removing them from Miscellaneous Files.

Deleting the .suo file from the solution directory solved the problem; however, doing so causes VS to forget which files you had open in the solution (and probably some other things).

Answer (score 6):

Still occurring in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, Version 15.8.6.

Deleting the `.suo` file (found in `.\.vs\YourSolutionName\v15\`) and rebuilding the solution fixed the issue.

I suspect it's known directory/targeted directory to search was being cached there because the Find Results would show up very quickly. Indicative of it not searching the "whole hard drive", or even my whole mapped workspace "Local Folder". Typically if I am performing a search on even a more parent branch in source control, it will take close to a minute.

Comment: I did not even have to rebuild the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to move the file .sln into the solution directory.